# Rails 2: use form_for to build a form covering multiple objects of the same class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is hopefully a slam dunk for a Rails maven :

I have a form that is supposed to iterate over a set of `LineItems` and gather information on each. I am trying to get `form_for` and `fields_for` to create the proper field names and parameters to give my controller a params hash something like

```
params[:line_items] = { <line_item.id> => { :rma_reason => "some string", :rma_qty => 2 } }
```

What I have is:

```
<% form_for(@object) do |rma_form| %>
  <% @order.line_items.each do |item| %>
  ....
    <% fields_for item do |item_f| %>
      <%= item_f.text_area :rma_reason %>
      <%= item_f.text_field :rma_qty, :value => item.quantity, :size=>3 %>
    <% end %>
  ....
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And the resultant HTML looks like (what you would expect, I guess):

```
<textarea id="line_item_id" name="line_item[id]"></textarea> 
<input id="line_item_rma_qty" name="line_item[rma_qty]" size="3" type="text" value="1" />
```

**However** what I am trying to get (and failing to find any solution beyond going back to ad-hoc HTML tags) is, field names that are indexed by the `line_item.id`, e.g. line_item[1928][rma_qty] for instance. This would allow my controller to iterate over each line_item and update it with the given params.

- ... maybe in a pure REST UI, the form should be tied to ONE instance of `LineItem`, and the standard form_for would work - but the user should be able to submit all the changes at once with one form. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fields_for needs to be called on the main form helper, and a string parameter with magic `[]`s and an argument indicating which instance should be inserted in the `[]`s

```
<% rma_form.fields_for "line_item[]", item do |item_f| %>
```

so now my tag looks something like

```
<input id="return_authorization_line_item_1070870205_rma_qty" name="return_authorization[line_item][1070870205][rma_qty]" size="3" type="text" value="1" />
```

which is peachy.

this [classic railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1) is a good fields_for intro, and [this comment](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for#357-Using-fields-for-with-has-many-associations) explains the effect of the magic bracket that did what I wanted - other than that, couldn't find this feature documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

When you're nesting form fields, you have to make sure you are chaining the `fields_for` methods form the appropriate form builder:

```
<% rma_form.fields_for :line_item, item do |item_f| %>
```

by calling `fields_for` alone, you were breaking the chain from `form_for` and thus the incorrect field names.

Comment: that didn't get me the line_item.id in the params, but you were right and it get me going down the road of figuring out how fields_for actually works - though it still seems very strange sometimes - thanks!

Comment: @sbeam my bad, I was missing the first param for `fields_for`. I think using symbols for model refs in these helpers is slightly more readable.