# Rails 3.1 multiple objects on one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've checked out a lot of questions for putting multiple objects on one form, but they seem to be out of date.

I have a bunch of user objects:

```
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = current_user
  end
```

that I need to edit in a form. They all have roles which will be edited on the form. The form is rendered in a partial, and nothing shows up, just 'admin form' plaintext.

```
users/_admin.html.erb
admin form
<% form_for "user[]", :url => users_path do |f| %>
<ul>
  <li class="layout">
    <div class="header"><h2>Users</h2></div>
    <table>
      <thead>
          ...
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
          <% puts "USER #{user}" %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= f.check_box(:editor) %></td>
              <td><%= f.check_box(:admin) %></td>
              <td><%= user.first_name %> <%= user.last_name %></td>
              <td><%= user.email %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </li>
</ul>
<%= submit_tag "Save"%>
<% end %>
```

Just the plaintext is rendered, **but no form**. Any ideas on how to fix it? I've tried the suggestions in these posts: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972857/multiple-objects-in-a-rails-form) [two](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219233/rails-2-use-form-for-to-build-a-form-covering-multiple-objects-of-the-same-class), but they're out of date.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `<%= .. %>` in Rails 3.1:

```
<%= form_for "user[]", :url => users_path do |f| %>
```