# Create two Objects within form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

i have the following code:

```
 <%= form_for Contact.new do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Name', style: 'width : 15ex' %>
   <%= f.text_field :phone, placeholder: 'Phone', style: 'width : 15ex' %>
   <%= f.text_field :note, placeholder: 'optional notes', style: 'width : 15ex' %>
   <%= submit_tag "Add", class: "btn btn-info pull-right" %>
 <% end %>
```

this works fine for one Contact, but if i want to create two objects by clicking on the add button its not working, here is the code for two contacts.

```
<%= form_for Contact.new do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Name', style: 'width : 15ex' %>
      <%= f.text_field :phone, placeholder: 'Phone', style: 'width : 15ex' %>
      <%= f.text_field :note, placeholder: 'optional notes', style: 'width : 15ex' %>
<% end %>
<%= form_for Contact.new do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Name', style: 'width : 15ex' %>
      <%= f.text_field :phone, placeholder: 'Phone', style: 'width : 15ex' %>
      <%= f.text_field :note, placeholder: 'optional notes', style: 'width : 15ex' %>
      <%= submit_tag "Add", class: "btn btn-info pull-right" %> 
<% end %>
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: If look at the generated HTML code, you'll see two forms, and a submit button can only submit one, that's probably why it's not working. But you should provide more information about WHAT is not working though, like error message, output, ...

Comment: Ok, so what would be the best way to generate two objects and submit it with one button?

Comment: Everything is working fine, the problem is only that it creates only 1 object, the first one, the second one doesnt get created.

Comment: @Antoine, that question doesn't provide an answer to the problem here. It's only about `<% form_for %>` vs `<%= form_for %>`.

Comment: Right, but the answer to the OP's question is actually there, I guess that's the main point

Comment: i looked at the Link Mischa postet, the link that @Antoine posted does not answer my question, its about displaying multiple objects within one form, i want to save/create two objects at once (submit) within a form, not displaying it.

Comment: @Fry you probably want to use javascript or ajax to do this, you would have something like add another contact documentation: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: ok, probably everyone is thinking to difficult. Just imagine the following: In the html i want to give the user the option to create two instead of one contacts, if he wants two, he just needs to fill out both textfields and click add. Thats all i want.

Comment: User nested attribute and nested form for you can add resources dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in two ways:

1. Using AJAX to submit dynamically the forms (maybe with [something like this](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)).
2. Use a custom submit method that iterates over an array of objects. Check the question Antoine posted on the comments ([link for consistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742105/rails-3-1-multiple-objects-on-one-form)) and note how the form receives params for `user[]`.

GL & HF.